# Problems auto-mounting samba/cifs share with fstab

Tags: samba, fstab, automount, cifs

I have been following the same tutorial that everyone else is [referencing](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently). My `fstab` entry is exactly like in the tutorial with changes to actual location. I keep getting the error

```
mount: only root can mount //freenas/Server on /media/Server
```

This is the most irritating thing I run into time and time again with running Ubuntu. I have had a freeNAS box with a single hard drive in it for almost 4 years. I had my server mounted correctly a month ago but I started from scratch again.

The server is functioning normally as I have another Ubuntu box running XBMC perfectly fine.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 but get the same message with 12.04.

I have installed `cifs-utils` and `smbnetfs` from terminal after installing samba from the software center. This is how I got it running last time.

The workgroup in samba matches my network workgroup.

I don't have any credentials to check with the share as it is setup as guest.

I can't browse the network as it keeps giving me a timeout error. I also can't open my share from Nautilus by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and manually typing my server share (`//freenas/Server`).

Edit 1: I'm able to browse my network but still am getting the error message?

Edit 2: I'm able to mount the share after testing the individual options one my one.  It seems that using `codepage=unicode` was causing the problem.  My fstab entry now looks like:

`//freenas/Media  /home/charles/Server  cifs  guest,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000  0  0`

Edit 3: I can only mount using only "guest" for options?  Last time I ran into an issue of not being able to open files on other computers that originated from my Ubuntu machine?

Last Edit:  I had to force my freeNAS server(Version: 0.7.2.5543) to have the same permissions as Ubuntu, `GID=1000` for `uid=1000`.  Also freeNAS by default creates a guest user account `ftp` with a null password.  With these three items and adding my freeNAS IP address to `/etc/hosts` I'm up and running.  Sorry for the super long delay closing this question but I greatly appreciate the help!

fstab entry:
`//freenas/Media  /home/charles/Server  cifs  username=ftp,password=,uid=1000  0  0`

Comment: Start by actually showing the line you are using to mount the share with fstab and the output of `ls -l` in `/media`.

Comment: //freenas/Media  /media/Server  cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode  0  0

Comment: I have tried making the folder "Server" with sudo mkdir or browsing through nautilus and manually creating the folder. I have tried mounting is /media, /mnt, and even /home/USER/.  I was able to mount my freenas share to my /home/USER/ after manually creating the folder via nautilus before I started fresh.

Comment: In your edit 2, is `uid1000` a typo here or a typo in your actual fstab? It should be `uid=1000`.

Comment: It was just a typo here John I will fix it, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your box is having difficulty resolving the IP of freenas via wins/netbios. Sometimes it is very difficult to resolve.

1. In your `/etc/fstab`, use ip address instead of hostname like following

   ```
    //192.168.1.100/Server
   ```
2. In your `/etc/hosts`, add following line

   ```
    192.168.1.100    freenas
   ```
3. `/etc/fstab`, use credential

   ```
    //freenas/Media /home/charles/Server cifs defaults,uid=1000,username=<user>,password=<pass> 0 0
   ```

Comment: I'm out of town but will try this when I get back.

Comment: I have tried both options John but have had no success.  From a stroke of luck I'm able to now browse my network and can see and use my server.  Any other suggestions to auto-mount the share?

Comment: If you are trying to mount from Nautilus, maybe try comment/remove the line from `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: I'm trying to auto-mount using fstab but can mount only if I have "guest" for options

Comment: Did you setup your freenas with guest only access? Or you want to connect with credential? Check (3).

Comment: FreeNAS is set up to give anonomyous(guest) access.  I'm having an issue that files I upload can be read but not changed even from the desktop I uploaded them with???  I thing that this is because I have only guest as options.  I can't make heads or tails from the man pages on how to properly configure fstab. If you know of a good tutorial or another reference that better explains the mount configurations please share.

Comment: I believe we will have to solve the issue from the freenas side. Is it possible you change the share directory owner on freenas to a uid=1000?

Comment: This is where it gets muddy, my freenas box is a lga755 pentium 4 and has an outdated version of freenas that I'm unable to update due to compatability.  I'm not that great with the server side of things as I can set up the box for samba but the advanced settings are lost on me.  The only thing on the freenas side I can tell that might help is that the default guest account name is "ftp".  I will try removing the "guest" option in fstab to replace with "user=ftp,password=".  I will continue to research how to set "uid=1000" on the server side.